# How to delete item within an item in json and C++ nlohmann::json

Tags: c++, json, nlohmann-json

I would like to know how I can delete an item within another item using [nlohmann::json](https://github.com/nlohmann/json) in C++.
I have looked at the documentation for [basic_json::erase](https://json.nlohmann.me/api/basic_json/erase/) but I can only see how to delete an item in the root of the json file, for example "Test" in my example json file.

Here is my json file:

```json
{
    "TEST":{
        "Age":10,
        "Name":"TEST",
        "Passwd":"null",
        "Username":"TEST"
    }
}
```

Here is my C++ file:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "src/json.hpp"
    
using namespace std;
using json = nlohmann::json;
    
int main()
{
    // parse
    cout << "Now parsing data/Accounts.json" << endl;
    ifstream AccountsFileRead("data/Accounts.json");
    json Accounts;
    AccountsFileRead >> Accounts;
    AccountsFileRead.close();
    cout << "Parsing successfully complete!" << endl;
    
    // read
    cout << "Now reading Accounts.json, account \"TEST\"\'s age" << endl;
    cout << Accounts["TEST"]["Age"] << endl;
    cout << "Reading successfully complete!" << endl;
    
    // change
    cout << "Now changing \"TEST\"\'s age to 0" << endl;
    Accounts["TEST"]["Age"] = 0;
    cout << Accounts["TEST"]["Age"] << endl;
    cout << "Changing successfully complete!" << endl;
    
    // delete
    cout << "Delete" << endl;
    // Here I want a simple way to delete Test's age.
    // For example something simple as: Accounts.delete["Test"]["Age"]

    // Save json
    ofstream AccountsFileWrite("data/Accounts.json");
    Accounts >> AccountsFileWrite;
    AccountsFileWrite.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Is there anyway I can possibly do this? I am new to C++ so please keep that in mind when answering.
Any help would be awesome!!

Comment: `Accounts["TEST"].erase("Age");` ?

Comment: Sorry @ChrisMM , That doesn't seem to work :( Thanks for trying to help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use a json_pointer:

```
auto json = nlohmann::json{<your json>};
auto path = nlohmann::json_pointer<nlohmann::json>{"TEST"};

auto& someTest = json[path];

// Erase from the 'someTest' node by key name
someTest.erase("Name");
```